# Tables width vary, can't control them

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I am working on an email newsletter template for someone, which obviously means I can't use CSS, and have to resort to using, of all things, tables. I have width stated *explicitly* for every cell and yet for some reason it screws up and is adding extra space, and I cannot figure out why. I've gone over every single line in the entire document, but I just can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. I really hate designing HTML for email. (I'm a Graphic Designer, my experience on the coding side is limited.) The page can be found at: http://www.coffeetalk.com/woowoo/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `th` Change `colspan="8"` to `colspan="11"`.

Also, you're already using plenty of CSS on this page. Why not use a little more?

Comment: As I understand it, it can be a dangerous business using CSS when your intended use is in email, especially when clients like Gmail outright strip the CSS out. I've tried to use as little as I can, but it's damn difficult working without CSS.

Thank you so much, that worked like a charm! You are my hero.